# print file content as quoted comma separated single line

Tags: awk, sed

How to print a file content as quoted and comma separated single line.

```
$cat test
file1.gz
file2.gz
file3.gz
file4.gz
```

I want to print as `'file1.gz','file2.gz','file3.gz','file4.gz'`

Comment: I just removed the "linux" tag. Please read descriptions of tags that you apply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}' file
'file1.gz','file2.gz','file3.gz','file4.gz'
```

or equivalent functionality but storing the whole input file in memory:

```
$ awk '{out=out sep "\047" $0 "\047"; sep=","} END{print out}' file
'file1.gz','file2.gz','file3.gz','file4.gz'
```

and abbreviated for the golfers :-):

```
$ awk -v q="'" '{o=o s q $0 q; s=","} END{print o}' file
'file1.gz','file2.gz','file3.gz','file4.gz'
```

Personally, I'd use the first script above unless you have some specific need to build up the whole output record before printing it, e.g. to modify it in some way based on a multi-line regexp.

Comment: Note that `'` is not always `\047`, but it's not that bad to write it portably: `awk "{printf \"%s'%s'"'", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}' input`

Comment: @WilliamPursell when is `'` not `\047`? Don't wrap scripts in double quotes as that exposes the rest of it to shell for interpretation and therein lies escaping/quoting/breaking hell (e.g. the $0 in your script would be the shell $0, not the awk one, and that print at the end I'm pretty sure would print a null string or the last record read depending on your awk version). If you WERE going to use a literal quote it'd be `awk '{printf "%s'\''%s'\''", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}' file`

Comment: I just noticed the front half of your script is in double quotes while the back half is in single quotes so my comment about what $0 and print "" mean is wrong since they're in the back half but IMHO that's not a great approach for clarity and consistency!

Comment: Thanks Ed, i like awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}'

or awk -v q="'" '{printf "%s%s", sep,q $0 q; sep=","}  END{print ""}'

Comment: In EBCDIC, single quote is 0x7D.  Indeed, this sort of thing does lead to quoting hell, but it's not that bad in this case, and if you look closely you'll see that the `$0` in my example is passed to `awk` and not expanded by the shell.  The double quote is terminated as soon as possible (immediately after the last single quote that needs to be printed.).  You're last example (using the variable `q` to be a single quote) is a great way to avoid this ugliness!

Comment: Geez, I haven't heard of EBCDIC in 40 years! I suppose it must still be out there in the wild... thanks for the info. I'll keep using `\047` until if/when EBCDIC rears it's head in a real application since it's convenient & will work on almost all machines but it's a good reminder that ASCII isn't all there is. Yeah, I saw your quoting switch after I posted my first comment.

Comment: The things I don't like about setting `q` to a single quote is you can't do that inside an awk script saved in a file to be run as `awk -f script` so you need to change to something else if you want to save your script in a file and you can't use it in every context, e.g. within a regexp literal, whereas `\047` works everywhere (EBCDIC systems excluded!)

Answer (score 3):

Convert one column to one row with separator. With sed and paste:

```
sed "s/.*/'&'/" file | paste -sd ","
```

Output:

```
'file1.gz','file2.gz','file3.gz','file4.gz'
```